# Components choice for chat gui

Tags: java, swing

In fact I just start actively practise swing in order my theoretical knowledge comes handy :) I've already done a lot for chat GUI implementation but at the end stuck with some issues. So I decided to rework chat GUI from scratch, but I need to make right choice of components for it.

At first, I must say that there's no "input" functionality in the first implementation.

My current chat implementation consists of the following components:

- JScrollPane to scroll up/down messages
- Each message is the JPanel with JLabel inside. JLabel works great with HTML so it is easy to change smiles tokens to . Also message constructs from two strings: sender's name and message. So again, support of HTML in JLabel lets us mark sender's name with  tag.

The reasons I think I'm stuck and chat GUI should be reworked from scratch:

- JLabel works with HTML but if you use JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, there's no more words wrap in it. Replacement of JLabel with JTextArea isn't good idea, cause JTextArea doesn't work with HTML.
- There's no possibility to scroll down scrollbars automatically when new message is added. At least I didn't manage to do it.
- It is difficult to control amount of components (JPanels with JLabels) to delete old ones when new message received from server. Otherwise it is possible to create hundreds of JPanels with JLabels in ten-fifteen minutes in an active chat. WeakReference is good here but usage of JPanel + JLabel for each message is bad design from the very beginning.

There're some other issues but they're not so critical and couldn't influence "rework decision".

I'd greatly appreciate if you could give a hint what components do suit well for such application like chat based on "reasons" described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is bad and you should feel bad.

Try to copy some text from a bunch of JLabel displayed contiguously.

Just use a JTextPane or something like that! This function is from a program of mine, in a class that extends JTextPane, it adds some text at the end, with some peculiar style. You can modify it to do whatever you need.

```
public void append(String append,Color fg,Color bg, boolean bold,boolean italic, boolean underline) {
    try {
        // Get the text pane's document                        
        StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument)this.getDocument();

        // The color must first be wrapped in a style
        Style style = doc.addStyle("StyleName", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, fg);
        StyleConstants.setBackground(style,bg);
        StyleConstants.setBold(style,bold);
        StyleConstants.setItalic(style,italic);
        StyleConstants.setUnderline(style,underline);


        // Insert the text at the end of the text
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), append, style);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.setCaretPosition (this.getDocument().getLength()-1);
}
```

Comment: No, not a JTextArea but rather a JList would be a better choice.

Comment: You're right, I feel bad :(
JTextArea doesn't work with HTML, so I won't be able to embed images, change background of some messages etc.

Comment: use JTextPane, it supports that stuff.

Comment: @LtWorf, you mean, wrap JTextPane in a JScrollPane in order to have ability to scroll messages. Then add new messages to JTextPane and delete old ones instead of creating mass of JPanels (in this case JTextPanes)?

Comment: Create just ONE JtextPane and put all the messages in it! If you want you can check how it is done in this project I made at university some time ago https://github.com/ltworf/anairc

Comment: @LtWorf, Thank you, I'll take a look at it. Btw, one more question. If I want to highlight some messages, for example, the ones that are addressed to me, are there such posibilities in JTextPane class? I looked through it but couldn't find anything, but set the whole JTextPane background.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a code example on how to do some things.

Comment: @LtWorf I agree with Hovercaft, a JList would be simpler and would more closely meet the requirements of the OP. And, yes, I've copied items from a JList, it's really rather simple

Comment: Actually the OP didn't mention a JList, and could you show me an example where you can copy an entire chat from a JList where there is one item per message?

Comment: @LtWorf, thanks again. It works faster than my "fail" variant, it is obvious. Cannot believe that it can be so easy, I mean I was ready to abuse swing left and right :D But there's a tricky moment I cannot overcome - the background you set with the Stlye. It only highlights a text leaving white spaces after it till the end of the window. Can you advise me anything on this?